# Android : multiple audio tracks in a VideoView?

Tags: android, audio, video

I've got some .MP4 video files that must be read in a VideoView in an Android activity. These videos include several audio tracks, with each one corresponding to a user language (eg. : English, French, Japanese...).
I've got unexpected trouble finding any help or documentation to provide such a feature. I'm currently able to load the video and play it in a VideoView with a MediaController, but not to change audio tracks.
I'm not sure the Android SDK provides any easy way to do this, which leaves me quite clueless on how to solve my problem. I was thinking of extracting every audio track, loading the audio that I want into a MediaPlayer depending on the language, then make audio and video play together. But I fear that some sync issues could arise and prevent me from doing this.
If you have any clue, any advice to help me getting started with this problem, you're more than welcome.

Comment: you seemed to have made progress based on the comment for the selected solution. Can you share how you accomplished the said task ?

Comment: This is kind of an old question but there's a simple solution to this problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested myself yet, but it seems that [Vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/#more-features) library has support for multiple audio tracks (among other interesting features). It is API-compatible with `VideoView` class from Android.

Probably you would have to use *Vitamio* `VideoView.setAudioTrack()` to set audio track (for example based on locale). See [Vitamio API docs](http://vov.io/vitamio/api/io/vov/vitamio/widget/VideoView.html#setAudioTrack%28int%29) for details.

Comment: In the end I did exactly what I suggested. I separated video and audio data, loading the audio into the MediaPlayer depending on user language, then syncing both streams. It was quite a dirty solution, but acceptable in the time I had to do the job.
I have not tested your solution, but I will accept it, as it seems to do exactly what I needed back then. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 5):

No 3rd party library required:

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("")); // set video source    

mVideoView.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        MediaPlayer.TrackInfo[] trackInfoArray = mp.getTrackInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < trackInfoArray.length; i++) {
            // you can switch out the language comparison logic to whatever works for you
            if (trackInfoArray[i].getTrackType() == MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO
                && trackInfoArray[i].getLanguage().equals(Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()) {
                mp.selectTrack(i);
                break;
            }
         }
         return true;
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell - audio tracks should be encoded in the 3-letter ISO 639-2 in order to be recognized correctly.

Comment: you wrote that audio track should be encoded in the 3 letter iso 639-2. Can you explain what it is?

Comment: Check out the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.html#getLanguage()

Answer (score 0):

Now you can Play Multiple audio track through ExoPlayer.

Here is the details,

1. https://exoplayer.dev/track-selection.html
2. [Exo Player Track Selection](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/exoplayer-2-x-track-selection-2b62ff712cc9#:%7E:text=When%20a%20piece%20of%20media%20contains%20multiple%20tracks%20of%20a,type%20it%20wishes%20to%20play.)

Answer (score -1):

VideoView class can't support your require.U must parse to get audio stream data(you want) to play with AudioTrack class on java layer.