# Android: Select audio track in video

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I've got some .mp4 videos that have multiple audio tracks, each for a specific language.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789529/android-multiple-audio-tracks-in-a-videoview) on stackoverflow but the user didn't post his solution.

I was wondering how to select one audio track from the .mp4 video and play it without hearing the other audio tracks at the same time?

I have no restraints as if it needs to be a VideoView or an Activity based on an Intent.ACTION_VIEW.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MediaPlayer.selectTrack(TrackIndex);`

to get track index use

```
findTrackIndexFor(TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO, MediaPlayer.getTrackInfo());

private int findTrackIndexFor(int mediaTrackType, TrackInfo[] trackInfo) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < trackInfo.length; i++) {
            if (trackInfo[i].getTrackType() == mediaTrackType) {

                return i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

can you please post that multi-track video files for me.