# Audio Video Playing together in android

Tags: android

I have mute video file and separate audio file for same video.  How can I play video with separate audio in android?  I have tried using VideoView but unable to play audio separately.  can anyone help in this!!

Comment: Have you managed to play the audio alone?

Comment: Yes. using mediaplayer

Comment: OK, and have you tried starting the videoview and playing the mediaplayer together?

Comment: Yes I did. but lacking syncronization

Comment: I don't think you're ever going to achieve great sync. What is reason that you need them in separate files?

Comment: I have single video file and for that I have two audio file having different language and based on language selected by user I want to play that audio with that video. can you suggest any solution for this?

Comment: Most video formats support multiple audio tracks. But actually this is an answer you might find useful with your files in their current form: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11360939/360211

Answer (score 0):

Before you start everything running, first you prepare both video and audio. When both of them are prepared only after that you can push the Start button.. and they should be synchronized ( if you recorded the audio part at the same time you started the video part)

Comment: can you provide example code for the same? Because have already tried it but when I move forward/backward only video is working and  no change in audio

Comment: you responded to weston question and you said that you tried to play both of them but they are lacking synchronization. You have 2 mediaplayers right ? (1 for video, 2nd for the audio). If yes, then you need to prepare() both of them, and since they are prepared (both of them!!!) you call the 'start()' method on both mediaPlayer instances. (I didn't worked for a while on android also using this class but as the documentation says: 'method prepare -> given state of mediaplayer{Initialized, Stopped}')

Comment: I play video(no sound available) on videoview and media player for audio. want to play both audio and video together. I am not using 2 mediaplayers.

Comment: In that case: when you audio is prepared, only after that you will start both videoView and audioMediaPlayer

Comment: No. Here are some links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827190/android-mediaplayer-onpreparedlistener , http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html

Comment: what is playing first: the video or the audio ?